# Automate Web Application clicks gestures for testing

Tags: testing, web-applications, browser

I have a web application and I want to automate everything I do (for testing things). It would be good if I could do it once and record it so that I can use it later on.

Basically, I have 2 ways to achieve this,

1) Front-end solutions like some browser extensions 
2) Back-end solutions like Selenium which can trigger everything from the server.

The problem with later is that I have to define everything in terms of code (maybe XPath or something) which is cumbersome. If there is a method to reproduce everything once I do it in a browser then that would be a better solution, including form filling, selecting drop-down etc. This is why I think a good solution could be a 50% front-end 50% back-end solution.

A frontend stuff that captures the elements I click/select and generates the code which can drive the back-end.

Basically, I am looking for a solution like this :

Start a session, record everything that gets done in the browser. Capture it for processing later on. Using Selenium or any other tool.

Is there anything like this available now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends very much on your application. I would give a try recording / playing back your testing with Selenium IDE Firefox plugin (http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/)